# How to enumerate all installed usb modem using Windows API

Tags: delphi, windows-7, usb, 32-bit, modem

I have bought a **ZTE MF190** usb modem and began to harness it.

So far, I have managed to programmatically have an sms sent to another mobile equipement using free **AsyncPro** components of *TurboPowers*.

I wonder wether there is a way to retrieve the **list of all installed modems** along with their attached serial COM ports (hopefully with other valuable capabilities).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To list the installed modems you can use the [`Win32_POTSModem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class

Check this sample code.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;


procedure  GetWin32_POTSModemInfo;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_POTSModem','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    Writeln(Format('AttachedTo      %s',[String(FWbemObject.AttachedTo)]));// String
    Writeln(Format('DeviceID        %s',[String(FWbemObject.DeviceID)]));// String
    Writeln(Format('Model           %s',[String(FWbemObject.Model)]));// String
    Writeln(Format('Name            %s',[String(FWbemObject.Name)]));// String
    Writeln(Format('PortSubClass    %s',[String(FWbemObject.PortSubClass)]));// String
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetWin32_POTSModemInfo;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode])); 
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;      
end.
```

Comment: +1: Thank you for answering. Is there also a way to do it without WMI?

Comment: Yes you can use the [RasEnumDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function or read the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}` Windows registry key.